# input: skip n lines

Tags: luatex, tex-core, input

I am trying to insert content from another file whilst optionally skipping the first n lines.  I have control over the inserted content, and my current solution is simply to wrap the first n lines in sequentially named macros which I can redefine to nothing, thereby suppressing the input.  This strikes me as rather ugly.

It seems `input` and `include` are not capable of skipping lines.  There are packages like `standalone`, but I'm not trying to remove content before a `begin{document}`, I'm just trying to skip lines in a `verse` environment.

Specifically my imported files look like this:

```latex
% lines.tex
line 1\\
line 2\\
line 3\\
```

Note that 'source lines' and 'output lines' are identical in this case, as exactly one output line ending in `\\` is found on one input line.  I don't really mind which I end up working on.

And I'm looking to do something like this:

```latex
\begin{verse}
\includelines[2]{lines} % skips first 2 lines
\end{verse}
```

I thought it would be relatively straightforward to iterate over the included content linewise, but having not found anything it seems this isn't really done.

If I am simply thinking in the wrong paradigm and the 'correct' way is to do as I am currently doing (wrap lines in macros which can be redefined later and thus not output anything) I don't mind sticking with that.

I am using `LuaLaTeX` anyhow, so I'm open to solutions using Lua.

### Current Solution

Currently I do this, but it clutters up both the document and the imported document.  I could avoid cluttering the document by wrapping the `\let`s in an environment, and using a number-to-word routine together with `\csname`.  But I was hoping for a solution which didn't requite cluttering up the *included* document.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% I define a long list of these, more than I will ever need
\def\printLine#1{#1}
\let\lineOne\printLine
\let\lineTwo\printLine
\let\lineThree\printLine
\let\lineFour\printLine
\def\dummy#1{}

\begin{verse}
  \let\lineOne\dummy
  \let\lineTwo\dummy
  % In reality we have an \input statement here
  \lineOne{line1\\}
  \lineTwo{line2\\}
  \lineThree{line3\\}
  \lineFour{line4\\}
  \let\LineOne\printLine
  \let\LineTwo\printLine
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `readarray` (which loads the `forloop` package).  The optional argument is the line to begin on rather than skip.  If you really prefer it the other way, let me know.

Two items to note (hat tip Marcel): 1) make sure you have the `[2021-09-17]` version of the `readarray` package, which will, with the setting `\ignoreblankreadarrayrecordstrue`, properly skip over fully commented lines when tabulating records from the input; 2) if a braced group spans more than a single line of the input file, the *record* that contains the group will contain the *whole* group, meaning that such a *record* will be seen to span several lines of input.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{lines.tex}
%
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
% A COMMENT IN THE FILE
Line 4
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2021-09-17]
\ignoreblankreadarrayrecordstrue
\newcounter{lino}
\newcommand\includelines[2][1]{%
  \readrecordarray{#2}\linearray
  \forloop{lino}{#1}{\thelino < \numexpr1+\linearrayROWS}
   {\ifnum\value{lino}>#1\\\fi
    \linearray[\thelino]}
}

\begin{document}
\includelines{lines.tex}

\includelines[2]{lines.tex}

\includelines[3]{lines.tex}

\includelines[4]{lines.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  `readarray` was exactly the kind of interface I was looking for.  I'll stick with this so I'm not tied to lua, although I'm much more at home in lua in general than TeX.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thank you for your comments.  The first issue was already resolved with the 2021-09-17 release of `readarray`, which I will add to the MWE.  The second issue is what it is.  Groups are preserved during the read.  I will note it in the answer.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I needed to activate `\ignoreblankreadarrayrecordstrue` to ignore the blank records.  As a result, I had to increase the loop terminus by 1, since the final blank record in the file is no longer counted as a record.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with pure TeX code, but here is a Lua solution (explanations added as comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newluafunction\skiplines
\directlua{
  % Some boilerplate
  local func = \the\allocationnumber
  token.set_lua('skiplines', func, 'protected')
  local input = token.create'input'
  lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
    % Read the number of lines to be skipped
    local count = token.scan_int()
    % Add a callback to change how TeX files are opened
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('open_read_file', function(name)
      % We only want to affect a single file, so we should remove the callback again.
      %% luatexbase.remove_from_callback('open_read_file', 'skip_input_lines')
      % But we delay this until TeX actually tries to read from the file since LaTeX might open the file multiple times.
      % Now open the file for reading
      local f = io.open(name, 'r')
      % If the file can't be opened we return nothing.
      if not f then return end
      % Remember if we are reading the first line
      local first = true
      % And return the reader table
      return {
        reader = function()
          % If TeX is trying to read the first line, unregister the callback and skip the first lines
          if first then
            luatexbase.remove_from_callback('open_read_file', 'skip_input_lines')
            for i = 1, count do f:read'l' end
            first = false
          end
          % Then just read a line and report it to TeX
          return f:read'l'
        end,
        % Remember to close the file when we are done with it
        close = function() return f:close() end,
      }
    end, 'skip_input_lines')
    % Finally add a \input to read the filename and initiate the reading.
    token.put_next(input)
  end
  % This code contains a small bug: If the file does not exists,
  % luatexbase.remove_from_callback will not be called and the
  % next time LaTeX tries to read a file the first lines get lost.
  % Avoiding this is complicated since LaTeX sometimes tries to
  % open non-existing files before opening the real one, so we can't
  % run remove_from_callback if the file doesn't exists.
  % It's not a big issue though since \input with a non existing filename is an error anyway,
  % So the issue only occurs if the compilation fails anyway. If a user chooses to ignore the
  % error message, they shouldn't expect sensible behavior afterwards.
}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
  Skip 0 lines:\\
  \skiplines 0{lines}
  after\\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  Skip 1 lines:\\
  \skiplines 1{lines}
  after\\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  Skip 2 lines:\\
  \skiplines 2{lines}
  after\\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  Skip 3 lines:\\
  \skiplines 3{lines}
  after\\
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  Skip 4 lines:\\
  \skiplines 4{lines}
  after\\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Maybe you are wondering why it looks like it skips one line less than expected: My version of `lines.tex` contains a comment in the first line (as in the question), so the first skipped line is the comment line which doesn't show in the output.

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely thorough and very easy to follow.  I'm going to leave it open a bit longer in case there's a plain TeX solution, but this is a whole lot less hacky than what I'm doing, and thus a whole lot better.  The 'bug' is indeed not a problem at all.

Comment: As an aside I had no idea how easy it was to override commands with Lua, I'll defintely be using that over plain TeX next time I want even remotely complicated behaviour